# Submit a JSF form using GET

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, http-get, viewparams

How do I submit a form to the same page and use GET parameters?

JSF page contents:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="item1" value="#{bean.item1}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="item2" value="#{bean.item2}"/>
</f:metadata>

...

<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{bean.item1}"/>
  <h:inputText value="#{bean.item2}"/>

  <h:button value="Submit" >
      <f:param name="item1" value="#{bean.item1}"/>
      <f:param name="item2" value="#{bean.item2}"/>
  </h:button>
</h:form>
```

If I request the page: form.jsf?item1=foo&item2=bar, it will populate the text fields, but the form submission to itself doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 15):

Replace `<h:button>` by

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="form?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"/>
```

It effectively fires a PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) which will include the `<f:viewParam>` params in the query string. Noted should be that the target page must have exactly same `<f:viewParam>`.

Another solution is to use a plain HTML `<form>` instead of `<h:form>`, give the input elements an `id` matching the parameter name and use a plain `<input type="submit">`. You can of course also use plain HTML `<input type="text">` here.

```
<form>
    <h:inputText id="item1" value="#{bean.item1}"/>
    <h:inputText id="item2" value="#{bean.item2}"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You should still keep the `<f:viewParam>` in both sides. You only need to realize that conversion/validation couldn't be done in this form, they have to be performed via the `<f:viewParam>` on the target page.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)

Answer (score 0):

You could also register a `NavigationHandler` that handles a keyword like 'self' and redirects to the the current view and adds the necessary query parameters.