# Form that submits using get

Tags: java, forms, get, jsf-2, form-submit

Is there any more elegant and JSF-Oriented way to create a form that submits using GET rather than using the following two methods:

1. Using normal `<form>` and `<input type="submit" />` tags
2. Firing up a Post-Redirect-Get. The first strategy does it ok with only one GET request, but I don't know if there is a better way to do.

I'm going with normal `<form>` and `<input type="submit" />` so far.

Obs: [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) expose those two known methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823216/jsf-2-0-form-using-get/4823289#4823289).

Comment: Hopefully this GET doesn't do anything bad to a database, and can't be reached via normal links, or you may be unhappy the next time a web crawler spiders your site ...

Comment: despite some old web crawlers, that only knows how to fire GET requests, and assuming the server side is not checking whether method is, GET has the same security as POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've ended up with standard html `<form>` and  `<input type="submit" />`. There's nothing wrong about it. 
**EDIT:** 
Except when I want to include view params. In that case, a Post-Redirect-Get is a way much better approach.