# Using GET parameters in JSF2

Tags: java, forms, jsf-2, get

I'm trying to pass form field values as GET parameters between 2 views (called "A" and "B").
In "B", I handle the parameters with f:metadata and f:viewParam. This part works great if I use the URL directly.

However, now I would like to pass fields from another view "A", but currenly without success. The fields are defined as follows:

```
<h:form>
<p:inputText id="field1" value="#{A.field1}"/>
<p:inputText id="field2" value="#{A.field2}"/>
[...]
</h:form>
```

If I use f:param within a Primefaces p:button, the parameters are transmitted but not retrieved dynamically (in fact, if I check the web page html code, the initial values of the form are written "statically").

What is the best approach to handle this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [`h:button`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) with [`f:param`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/param.html):

```
<h:button outcome="B.xhtml" value="Click me!">
    <f:param name="maybe_an_id" value="3" />
</h:button>
```

This will generate a normal HTML button, with a Javascript on click like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me!"
  onclick="window.location.href='/path/to/B.xhtml?maybe_an_id=3'; return false;">
```

**See also:** [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With "static" parameters everything works fine, but I would like to have something similar to `<f:param name="field1" value="#{A.field1}"/>

Comment: EL is valid there too, so you can use something like `#{param.field1}`. Check out [EL implicit objects](http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/help/2update1/jsp-jsfel/jsf_expression_language_intro.html#implicitobjects).

Comment: The problem is that only the "initial" values of the form are sent. If I modify fields, the changes are not sent. I guess there is some trick to do, since the form uses a POST method (maybe POST/Redirect/GET) but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ah, I think I understood, what you want is a plain HTML form with method="get", see [the second part of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4823289/149872). If you just want to submit the same values, why not just use POST with an `h:commandButton` instead?

Comment: I finally understood what was my problem. I tried a commandButton with "faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" (in A.xhtml) which didn't add any GET parameters. It was simply that in B.xhtml, I had to refer (with viewParam) to "A" bean fields (I used f:viewParam value="#{B.field1}" instead of f:viewParam value="#{A.field1}"

Comment: yeah, if you only go to B from A, that will work. glad you solved it!