# JSF How to submit a form and pass the values as GET params to another page?

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2.2, http-get, viewparams

Hi I see this anwer by BalusC [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/creating-master-detail-pages-for-entities-how-to-link-them-and-which-bean-scope)

What i am looking for is a way to pass an input value as a request GET param. 
Suppose I have a page1 with search form like this:

```
<h:form>                              
  <h1>Search</h1>                
  Search Person
  <p:inputText value="#{personBean.personName}"/>                  
  <p:commandButton value="Find" action="personData.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>                                
</h:form>
```

And have a second page (page2) to show the person´s data like this:

```
<h:head>
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="personName" value="#{person}" converter="#{personConverter}"converterMessage="bla bla"
                     required="true" requiredMessage="bla bla" />                      
 </f:metadata>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
        <p:messages/>

        Here show person Data.....
</h:body>
```

My question is how to pass the input value from page1 as a GET request param to page2, so in this way i can have bookmarkeability in page2. Thanks in advance. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: How is this omnifaces related? And did you try posting the title of your question in google (with jsf added?) lots of hits... And right here in the 'related' column to

Comment: Yes but nothing works for me. I see o:form and try to understand how its works and balusC is one of the creators of omnifaces and answers a lot of questions here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a JSF form using GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823216/jsf-2-0-form-using-get)